# Aggregated structure constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, structure

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Point {
    double x,y;
    Point(double x=0, double y=0): x(x), y(y) {}
};

struct Triangle {
    Point A,B,C;
    Triangle(Point A=Point(), Point B=Point(), Point C=Point()): A(A), B(B), C(C) {}
    void output()
    {
        cout<<"A: "<<A.x<<";"<<A.y<<endl;
        cout<<"B: "<<B.x<<";"<<B.y<<endl;
        cout<<"C: "<<C.x<<";"<<C.y<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Triangle t;
    t.output();
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine. My question is about the `Triangle` constructor with default parameters. Is this a correct way to initialize the members by calling the `Point` constructor like this `Point A=Point()` (in terms of efficiency and clean code)?

Comment: Another option not mentioned yet is to get rid of the `Triangle` constructor entirely, and allow the user to use aggregate initialization

Comment: @M.M, yes, but what if I need to write `Triangle t;` without any initializers? What about compiler warnings and/or clean code?

Comment: `Triangle t;` looks pretty clean to me

Comment: For clean code, it would be about semantic: Does it really make sense to allow to write (non explicit btw) `Triangle(pA)` or this one `Triangle(pA, pB)`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a correct way to initialize the members by calling the Point constructor like this Point A=Point() (in terms of efficiency and clean code)?

It is correct.

You can't talk about efficiency with just one method. You need to present a second method and then compare them for efficiency.

As far as cleanliness is concerned, I think it is better to use function argument names that are different than member variables.

The compiler will create correct code when you use

```
Triangle(Point A=Point(), Point B=Point(), Point C=Point()): A(A), B(B), C(C) {}
```

but it is more human readable to use

```
Triangle(Point inA = Point(), Point inB = Point(), Point inC = Point()): A(inA), B(inB), C(inC) {}
```

Comment: As for efficiency: I thought there might be another way of doing this more efficiently. That is why I asked about it. But still thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In terms of code cleanliness I would prefer to present two constructors instead:

```
Triangle(Point inA, Point inB, Point inC): A(inA), B(inB), C(inC) {}
Triangle() : Triangle(Point(), Point(), Point()) {}
```

Comment: Better yet `Triangle() {}`